# Adding Product Image in My Product Reviews page

Tags: product-images, review

friends. How to add product images on the My Product Reviews page like this mockup design

[image: My Product Reviews page with product images]

Answer (score 5):

The product collection with the reviews is built in `Mage_Review_Block_Customer_List::_construct()` but the collection contains only the name attribute of the product.
So you need to rewrite that method and add the image attribute.
So create your module and add this in the config.xml

```
<blocks>
     <review>
         <rewrite>
             <customer_list>[Namespace]_[Module]_Block_Customer_List</customer_list>
         </rewrite>
     </review>
</blocks>
```

then create the file `[Namespace]/[Module]/Block/Customer/List.php` with this content

```
<?php 
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Block_Customer_List extends Mage_Review_Block_Customer_List
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->collection->addAttributeToSelect('image');
    }
}
```

Then in the template `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/review/customer/list.phtml` add this to get the image where ever you need it like this:

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_review, 'image')->resize(200,150)?>" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_review->getName())?>" />
```

Feel free to change the size of the image to what ever you need.

Comment: Hi Marius (@marius), thanks for help and very fast answer. I have try it but the result is No Image Available [http://i.imgur.com/2ddw6aw.png]. I have try with extend it to code\local\Mage\Review, but it did not work. Then I make module code\local\KS\Myreview, but it did not work too. The following is my code link : [http://pastebin.com/jr4rGm9m] (sorry, should I put it as a link in the comments or put my question / edit questions based on your guidelines?). I have clear cache and make sure image of product in admin set to Base Image for each store view.

Comment: and somehow I did not know it sometimes makes my apache crashes

Answer (score 1):

I did not create a new module and not also make extend. I tried the following in app\design\frontend\andi\default\template\review\customer\list.phtml and successfully.

```
<?php foreach ($this->getCollection() as $_review): $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_review->getEntityPkValue());?>

<a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(160,227); ?>" width="160" height="227" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'image'), null, true) ?>" />
```

[image]